# Initializer configuration setting in proc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proc

The [Knock gem](https://github.com/nsarno/knock/) for Rails generates an initializer that has a configuration setting value within a `Proc`. Then the `Proc` is executed with the `.call` [in the code](https://github.com/nsarno/knock/blob/66b60437a5acc28e4863f011ab59324dc1b5d0ae/test/model/knock/auth_token_test.rb#L8). Why is this configuration attribute being set to a Proc and not simply just `Rails.application.secret_key_base`?

```
config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.secret_key_base }
```

Comment: Could it be lazy loading? Using a Proc lets knock evaluate it later instead of at the time the app is initialized.

Comment: @max Yeah, just seems unusual for a simple string value.

Comment: The thing is that its not just a simple string literal. Its read from a file.